# Clang AST : extern LinkageSpec issue

Tags: c++, clang, abstract-syntax-tree, extern

I'm currently writing a static C++ code analyser using clang's python bindings and for some reason, I can not find wether something is `extern` or not in the AST eventhough there is a CursorKind which seems to be apropriate (CXCursor_LinkageSpec)

What I mean is that when parsing code like `extern int foo;` I will only find my variable `foo` in the AST and not a single clue of its linkage specifications.

What am I missing?
Regards

Comment: Note: this happens for libclang in C too.

Answer (score 3):

class VarDecl has a member function:
*bool hasExternalStorage () const* 
which tells you whether the variable is extern or not.

I'm using clang's C++ lib. Hope it will help with your python work.

Comment: And for functions (FunctionDecl) there is [getStorageClass](https://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1FunctionDecl.html#a6d1ca48abb2608409dcd2a9261d555bc), you can check if it's equal to SC_Extern (`clang::StorageClass::SC_Extern`)

Answer (score 3):

Bit of a necroanswer but if you go in to clang\lib\Sema\SemaCodeComplete.cpp(in \llvm\tools\ if you follow llvm's installation instructions) and add the following line:

```
case Decl::LinkageSpec:  return CXCursor_LinkageSpec;
```

To the switch in:

```
CXCursorKind clang::getCursorKindForDecl(const Decl *D)
```

It should resolve the issue of clang's Python binder returning UNEXPOSED_DECL instead of the correct LINKAGE_SPEC.  This change was made at revision 183352(2013-06-05).

Example from my version:

```
CXCursorKind clang::getCursorKindForDecl(const Decl *D) {
if (!D)
    return CXCursor_UnexposedDecl;

switch (D->getKind()) {
    case Decl::Enum:               return CXCursor_EnumDecl; 
    case Decl::LinkageSpec:  return CXCursor_LinkageSpec;
   // ......
```

Comment: This change has been proposed multiple times, most recently by me, but nobody seems to care enough to accept it. Sigh.

Comment: @Cameron 3 years and this issue is still a thing?  Yikes.

Comment: This issue is finally fixed in clang 18.1.0, released in March 2024. https://releases.llvm.org/18.1.0/tools/clang/docs/ReleaseNotes.html#libclang: `clang::getCursorKindForDecl` now recognizes linkage specifications such as `extern "C"` and reports them as `CXCursor_LinkageSpec`.